# Why does HttpURLConnection.getInputStream() have intermittant delays?

Tags: android, performance, delay, httpurlconnection

I'm seeing intermittent delay on getInputStream returning and also intermittent slow reads on the
input stream.

I'm using an asynch HttpURLConnection to execute a GET on a server.  The server returns an XML
String.  I'm watching the server transactions using Fiddler and the transactions out and back to the
server are consistent (relative to execution of the Android app) at around 250-600 ms.  Execution 
on the Android device though can stretch into 10+ s.  I have tried the performance with the stand
alone device, on the same wireless network, but I see the same long intermittent delays.  Sometimes
I get a socket timeout exception.

My app is running on a HiSense Android tablet.  I'm directing the android
traffic through the Fiddler proxy on a notebook.    I'm using debug mode
 via USB to capture some timing data from the code.  The timer_value gets set by my activity when 
 it kicks off the asynch task.  Log times are cumulative in ms from the start of the asynchTask.

I can see that it is not a DNS problem from Fiddler.  I have tried to close the connection first
 before starting a new one.  I have tried turning off "keep-alive".  I have looked potential impact
  of cookie synchronization...  Any ideas?

Here is the code from the asynchTask:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"top of background = " + Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() 
        - ((MyApplication)activity.getApplicationContext()).timer_value) ); 

    URL url;
    InputStream is = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try {
        char[] buffer = new char[2000]; 
        int count=0;
        url = new URL(urls[0]);

        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"in front of connect = " +    Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() 
            - ((MyApplication)activity.getApplicationContext()).timer_value) ); 

        connection.connect();

        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"time to connect = " + Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() 
            - ((MyApplication)activity.getApplicationContext()).timer_value) ); 

        is = connection.getInputStream();

        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"time to response = " + Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() 
            - ((MyApplication)activity.getApplicationContext()).timer_value) ); 

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");        

        while ((count = reader.read(buffer,0,1500)) > 0) {      

            response = response.append(new String(buffer, 0, count));
             Log.v(LOG_TAG,"time so far in read loop = " + Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() 
                - ((MyApplication)activity.getApplicationContext()).timer_value) );                        

        }
        is.close();
        reader.close();

        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"time to read = " + Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()
            - ((MyApplication)activity.getApplicationContext()).timer_value) );                        

        return response.toString();

        } 
        catch (Exception e) {   
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"exception = " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } 
    }
```

Here is a LogCat which is faster than most.  Fiddler shows the transaction taking 24 ms.  I timed 
the full code at 441 ms:

```
09-16 16:21:44.287: V/kinn_nat5(13131): time to connect = 9
09-16 16:21:44.567: V/kinn_nat5(13131): time to response = 295
09-16 16:21:44.707: V/kinn_nat5(13131): time to read = 434
09-16 16:21:44.717: V/kinn_nat5(13131): time to complete = 441
09-16 16:21:44.757: D/dalvikvm(13131): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 350K, 11% free 6673K/7495K,    paused 21ms, total 21ms
09-16 16:21:44.847: D/dalvikvm(13131): GC_CONCURRENT freed 281K, 10% free 6813K/7495K, paused 2ms+11ms, total 25ms
```

When it goes badly, it could generate a timeout or horrible delays like these for a transaction 
which Fiddler clocked at 47 ms.  Here I timed it at 18 seconds!  Any ideas?

```
09-16 16:27:55.217: V/kinn_nat5(14093): top of background = 1
09-16 16:27:55.217: V/kinn_nat5(14093): time to connect = 9
09-16 16:28:13.247: V/kinn_nat5(14093): time to response = 18040
09-16 16:28:14.037: V/kinn_nat5(14093): time to read = 18825
09-16 16:28:14.087: D/dalvikvm(14093): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 266K, 11% free 6716K/7495K, paused 52ms, total 52ms
09-16 16:28:14.097: V/kinn_nat5(14093): time to complete = 18889
09-16 16:28:14.187: D/dalvikvm(14093): GC_CONCURRENT freed 375K, 10% free 6801K/7495K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 15ms
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Fiddler, but I assume that you get similar results when not routing through this proxy? Any chance your server is to blame?

Comment: Correct.  If I operate the tablet alone, I observe the delays.  Fiddler, http://www.telerik.com/fiddler , let's you debug traffic coming into and out of platforms.  I can see that the server is fine by looking at the timing summary of the http request and response to/from the server.  Desktop access using browser has no performance issues.  Tonight, I'm thinking this must have something to do with transactions still waiting for completition and then waiting for them to become available again for reuse...

Answer (score 0):

After swapping tablets to try and debug this issue, I now suspect that the root cause is the performance or the particular Android release of the HiSense tablet I have been using.

When I use an Asus Nexus 7 running Android 4.4.4 in debug mode, same amount of memory, but with a significantly beefier CPU, and newer version of the OS, the system performs like a champ.  I have seen no timeouts, and the performance is very close to what I see from Fiddler.  The systems performs well with or without keep-alive turned on.

I'm not sure why the performance of the Hisense is so bad.  I don't have time to understand that.  That machine is running 4.1.1 and operating pretty much as it came out of the box, so I have no idea.  I

Below is a typical transaction which Fiddler clocked at 440 ms.  My timing shows completion in 509 ms.

```
09-17 12:44:42.880: V/kinn_nat5(10361): top of background = 0
09-17 12:44:42.880: V/kinn_nat5(10361): in front of connect = 1
09-17 12:44:42.880: V/kinn_nat5(10361): time to connect = 4
09-17 12:44:43.381: V/kinn_nat5(10361): time to response = 498
09-17 12:44:43.391: V/kinn_nat5(10361): time to read = 508
09-17 12:44:43.391: V/kinn_nat5(10361): time to complete = 509
09-17 12:44:43.521: D/dalvikvm(10361): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 800K, 8% free 10280K/11116K,    paused 17ms, total 17ms
```

Comment: Http performance of the HiSense tablet improves a ton if you set background processes to 0 in Developer options.